# How to get to Telavi from Tbilisi by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, georgia-country, tbilisi

My traveller friend here in Tbilisi wants to go visit someone in Kakheti, probably in Telavi.

But Georgia is not the most well documented travel destination and we're having trouble finding how to get there.

Perhaps there's a Marshrutka the whole way but more likely is a bus (coach) going from one or other of the major bus stations. But if so which station (Ortachala? Didube?) and which company and how frequently do they depart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Dutch travel site called [`hansrossel.com` has a page on Telavi](http://www.hansrossel.com/travel-information/georgia-tbilisi/telavi.htm) including how to get there from Tbilisi:

> **Travel by public transport : Bus Tbilisi - Telavi**, since 2002 there are brand new buses running 5 times per day (last bus departs around 17:00) from Samgori station (reachable by metro), about  2 hours traveling. (From Didube station there are no buses.)

(I've edited the quote for clarity and spelling)

Answer (score 2):

From Tim Burford's guide: "For Telavi, there are between 6 and 8 buses a day from Ortachala costing 6 lari. Occasional shared taxis also leave for Telavi from the square north of Isani Metro."

Comment: Would the guide you refer to be this one? **[Georgia with Armenia (Bradt Travel Guides) \[Paperback\]](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Georgia-Armenia-Bradt-Travel-Guides/dp/184162053X/ref=dp_ob_title_bk/280-4333060-2156717)**